# salt-cloud -m 'cloud.map' hangs on Warning: Permanently added <ip address> (RSA) to list of known addresses

Tags: macos, python-2.7, provisioning, digital-ocean, salt-stack

Executing the command in the CLI:

```
sudo salt-cloud -m 'cloud.map'
```

...ends up hanging with the message:

```
Warning: Permanently added <ip address> (RSA) to list of known addresses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem appears to have happened because `pip` was referencing the *old* `salt-cloud` command. Salt-stack has integrated `salt-cloud` into the main branch.

Removing `salt-cloud` using:

```
pip uninstall salt-cloud
```

corrected the problem by allowing the command line to reference the right program.